# PHP get total in multiple loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am using the following script where in I want the total projects of a particular branch,  the tables are as follows --

Tbl_branch has -

Branch Id | 
Branch Name

Tbl_employee has -

emp_id | 
bid (branch id ) | 
emp_details

Tbl_Project has -

id | project_details | emp_id(which employee added the project)

--

Here I want to get total projects of a particular branch where in the user will select the branch name through a dropdown and its id will be in the value.

I am using the following query

```
<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_employee WHERE bid = '$bid'");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$eid = $row1['id'];

$pro = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_project WHERE emp_id = '$eid'") or     die(mysql_error()); 
$rowpro = mysql_fetch_array($pro);
$totalprojectsb = $rowpro[0]; 

 ?>

<div class="card-container col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card card-red hover">
              <div class="front">        
                <h1>Total Enquires</h1>
                <p id="users-count"><?php echo $totalprojectsb; ?></p>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x pull-right">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x"></i>
                  <span class="easypiechart" data-percent="100" data-line-width="4"   data-size="80" data-line-cap="butt" data-animate="2000" data-target="#users-count" data-update="3000" data-bar-color="white" data-scale-color="false" data-track-color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <ul class="inline divided">
                  <li>
                    <h1>Total Projects </h1>
                    <p><?php echo $totalprojectsb; ?></p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <h1>This Month</h1>
                    <p><?php  ?></p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="summary negative"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> </div>

              </div>
            </div>

<?php } ?>
```

This shows the total tile as many times as the total number of employees in that branch.

All I want here is to show one tile which will get the total number of projects from one particular branch. 
I saw somewhere array could be used for such things but I am not sure how.

Please help. Also correct my question if not properly framed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as long as you are interested only in total number of project on particular branch, you could just change your SQL as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM Tbl_Project
WHERE emp_id IN (
    SELECT emp_id
    FROM Tbl_employee
    WHERE bid = '$bid'
)
```

This query should return total number of project on selected branch

Edit: to clarify a bit: The inner `SELECT` selects all employee which are working on that branch, the outer `SELECT` select all project, that was created by employees selected in inner `SELECT` (eg. project on that branch). The `COUNT` only count such projects.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the following: "*Here I want to get total projects of a particular branch where in the user will select the branch name through a dropdown and its id will be in the value.*" -> That is, irrelevant of which user is currently logged in, or whose projects it is, you want to classify them based on the branch they are associated with (through the various employees who belong to a given branch and have created the project).

```
SELECT b.branchid, b.branchname, count(p.projectid) AS branchProjects FROM tbl_employee AS e
    LEFT JOIN tbl_project AS p ON p.empid = e.empid
    LEFT JOIN tbl_branch AS b ON b.branchid = e.bid
    GROUP BY b.branchid
```

With the above SQL, you will be connecting your tables and grouping the received data by the `branchID`, and counting the results which are connected to them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But how do I use it to get the total number of the projects of a branch ?   P.S - I am just a newbie so dont know how to use the above query

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure which part of your HTML should contain the name of the branch? Because I see a heading for `Total projects`, and heading for `Total Enquiries` where you're inserting all projects associated with an employee, but not where you want to place the name of a branch.

Comment: I am showing the branch name in the title of the page and this section is where I am stuck so didn't paste the code of whole page. Also In the total enquiries / total projects i want to show the total projects of the particular branch selected by the user, which is received via post in this page and saved in variable - bid   ..........P.S - @Drecker's - answer got it working. Hope that makes the question more clear...:)

Comment: Alright, I thought you were seeking to list all of the available branches (that are stored in the database) and the projects associated with them, so not just one particular branch (identified by the `bid` variable). Glad you got it solved.